# SET SESSION optimizer_switch = 'condition_fanout_filter=off' for optimization in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I used

```
SET SESSION optimizer_switch = 'condition_fanout_filter=off' ;
```

inside the stored procedure. Keeping in mind that the procedure consists of SELECT commands only. No insert, update and deleted operations are performed. The procedure was optimized and the data returned quickly.
But what I noticed an impact of `SET SESSION optimizer_switch = 'condition_fanout_filter=off'` in all stored procedures rather than single procedure. I found this detail by executing `SHOW VARIABLES` command in MySQL.
It displayed condition_fanout_filter=off instead of condition_fanout_filter=on.
Can anybody explain why it happened? Is it a bug in MySQL? Does it mean that SESSION turned into GLOBAL? If YES then WHY?

I tried to optimize a single stored procedure by using `SET SESSION optimizer_switch = 'condition_fanout_filter=off'` but this impact occurred on all stored procedures in database.

Comment: we can see what is in your stored procedure, but basically the optimizing is there the same as in a normal query as well. Loops for example a costly and some other concpets also. So ass all information you have on tables indexes (create table) and specially the code of the procedure

Comment: Indexes are already created in the table that is used in stored procedure. Initially it took 13 seconds to display the data after executing the procedure call and now it's taking 6 seconds to show the data as there is huge amount of data inside the table. 6 seconds seems reasonable. But the impact of SET SESSION optimizer_switch = 'condition_fanout_filter=off'; occurred on all stored procedures which should not happen as SET SESSION statement is used in single procedure only.

Comment: the re is no automated otinizing, in the source code you can manipulate what the optimizer will do, but at the end you need to check every query in your procdure and optimize it, what indexes you have i can't see, so if they are good for the case you have, is not determine

Comment: thanks I got an answer. I opened a new session and found condition_fanout_filter=on. It means that whenever we open a current session, the change would appear for that particular session only.

Comment: good write a self explantory answer maybe others have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

`SET SESSION` applies to the connection, including all stored procs subsequently called by the connection.

`SET GLOBAL` applies to the system, and provides a *default* that is provided to each connection when it starts.  It applies until the next restart of mysqld, hence, it is not as "permanent" as changing the config file.

"PERSIST" turns "GLOBAL" into essentially a change to the config file.

With a different syntax, some settings can be made to apply to a single statement -- this is with "optimizer hints" (qv).  Hints can backfire -- what works well today may not work tomorrow after the distribution of data in the table has changed.

The Optimizer analyzes each statement just before it runs it.  That is, the same query may be run in different ways (eg with/without using an index) depending on the data and the parameters (especially constants in `WHERE`).  Hints inhibit this dynamic flexibility.

*Some* settings do not follow the above rules.